# preventDefault in bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with twitter bootstrap and I've got this code

```
$('.addYT').on('click', function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    event.preventDefault();
}).popover({
    placement: 'bottom',
    html: true,
    content: function(e) {
        return $('.YTadd').html();
    }
});​
```

Everything works fine but in the `popover content:` there is a html code with something like `<a href="#">`. I want it to be preventDefault. But it doesnt work. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: `'true'` is a string if you want to pass a boolean value you should remove the quotes.

Comment: Still this does not solve my problem :S

Comment: Never mind, I solved this already

Comment: @Chanckjh it would be helpful for others if you answer your question and put your solution in the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I've answered this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373357/bootstrap-popover-preventdefault-for-click-is-not-working-in-a-rails-3-2-app

Comment: popover in bootstrap is dynamically generated : answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19719281/event-preventdefault-doesnt-work-with-button