# bootstrap popover preventDefault for click is not working in a Rails 3.2 app

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript

Someone else asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231461/preventdefault-in-bootstrap-popover), but there was no answer or solution given.

These bootstrap files are listed at the top of my application.js file:

```
...
//= require bootstrap-tooltip
//= require bootstrap-popover
...
```

My bootstrap_additions.js.coffee file contains:

```
$("a[rel=popover]").popover()
$(".tooltip").tooltip()
$("a[rel=tooltip]").tooltip()
```

In a view I have:

```
<a href="#" class="btn" rel="popover" title="Title" data-content="Some content.">click</a>
```

When i enter localhost:3000/assets/application.js in the browser, the bootstrap-popover.js content is present. In addition i found the following:

```
jQuery(function() {
    $("a[rel=popover]").popover().on('click', preventDefault());
    $(".tooltip").tooltip();
    return $("a[rel=tooltip]").tooltip();
});
```

When the link is clicked the browser display is moved to the top of the page. When I scroll back down to the link, the popover is displayed. All is working except preventDefault. What am I missing?

Thanks.

---

UPDATE: To keep things clean in my code, i found the [coffeescript version](http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/preventdefault) of the selected answer:

```
$("a[rel=popover]").popover().click (e) => e.preventDefault()
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using [Twitter Bootstrap Popover](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers)

**Updated to be in Coffeescript**

**1st approach**

Instantiate

```
$("a[rel=popover]").popover()
```

Handle

```
$("a[rel=popover]").click (event) ->
  event.preventDefault()
  event.stopPropagation()
  $(this).popover "show"
```

**2nd approach**

Taken directly from their source code:

```
$("a[rel=popover]").popover().click (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
```

Comment: This is not the solution i would recommend, but it works. I updated my question with the recommended solution. If you add the coffeescript version to your answer, I'll remove the update from my question.

Answer (score 15):

You can also chain as this :

```
$("a[rel=popover]")
  .on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  })
  .popover();
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use a 'span' tag instead of an 'a' tag so that you don't need to preventDefault.

also prevent default should be associated with an event.

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear:  Using a span tag would mean that you don't have to preventDefault, so try using a span tag.  And (as another note) you need to pass an event to preventDefault.

Comment: You said, "you need to pass an event to preventDefault" but the documentation clearly says, "This method does not accept any arguments." You are already calling preventDefault() on the event object itself.

Comment: I believe he means you need to attach it to an event -- e.preventDefault(); -- though I could be mistaken

Comment: yes, my apologies...i did mean that...bad or careless choice of words.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I want to thank TontonBlach for his answer because it greatly helped me.

I wondered however why this simple feature wasn't working and having read the official manual (as opposed to W3 schools) at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#popovers I have found what I believe is the correct answer.

1. Firstly there should be no href tag
2. > For proper cross-browser and cross-platform behavior, you must use the `a` tag, not the `button` tag, and you **also must include the role="button" and tabindex attributes**

What fixed it was copying their (working) example and noting the differences (which for me was the absence of tabindex). Also worth noting that role="button" is to do with accessibility and so not *technically* required.

With this in place you can then correctly use the default `.popover()` function to initiate the popovers.