# event.preventDefault() doesn't work with button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is it `.preventDefault()` doesn't work or even `alert()` on my form?

```
<div id="popover-head" class="hide">Add new tab</div>
<div id="popover-content" class="hide">
    <form class="form-inline" id="myForm"  method="POST" action="../admin/FLT_add_tab.do">
    <div class="form-group">
        <!-- my form -->
        <input type="text" name="newTab"/>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" ><i class="icon-white icon-ok"></i></button>
        <button class="btn" type="button" onClick="popRemove();" ><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
    </div>
     </form>
</div>
```

The JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) { 
        alert("Thank you for your comment!" + e);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong.

**UPDATE:**

link that has the popover:

```
<li><a href="#" id="popover"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i> Tab</a></li>
```

JS that trigger the popover"

```
$('#popover').popover({ 
    html : true,
    title: function() {
      return $("#popover-head").html();
    },
    content: function() {
      return $("#popover-content").html();
    }
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9uYuH/

Comment: is the form dynamically generated ?

Comment: Try writing it in regular JavaScript with an `onsubmit` and check for errors; jQuery’s #1 rule is “fail silently”

Comment: i fiddled it here http://jsfiddle.net/j59Rr/ and it seems to working fine!

Comment: This code works for me. So what do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: @optionaloptional sorry I don't know how to make it in the fiddle because it is a popover of the bootstrap.

Comment: @newbie you should check whether you have included the jquery in your code or not?

Comment: @TusharGupta I'm not that sure. But I think its not. I updated the question for more clearer view for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As popover in bootstrap generated dynamic elements you can not bind events directly to them .So you have to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$(document).on('submit','#myform', function(e) { 
    alert("Thank you for your comment!" + e);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

or Better use

```
$('#popover').on('submit','#myform', function(e) { 
    alert("Thank you for your comment!" + e);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Syntax

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

Comment: ah yeah its working this way. Thank you. I will accepting this answer because its more detailed

Comment: @newbie i was ready with this answer as you posted the question.That's why i asked `is the form dynamically generated ?` .Than i confirmed about `popover` than answered .

Answer (score 4):

since popover in bootstrap is dynamically generated, you should use the following jquery function

```
$(document).on('submit','#myform', function(e) { 
    alert("Thank you for your comment!" + e);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```